# Multitrack player with 0 latency

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, web

I have a big challenge.
Currently searched on the internet, content that could help me with this question: I need to develop a Multitrack Player as those of music recording studios.
The idea is to make 3 or more MP3 files play at the same time, simultaneously and synchronized like a player example of this page: http://www.multitracks.com/songs/Steffany-Gretzinger/The-Undoing/Constant-One/

Ok. I have used the `<audio>` of html5. 0 of latency on a user of PC. But when testing realized on a cell phone, audio is out of sync. For there is a minimum latency of 1 second or longer to begin each tag `<audio>`.

I have also tested `Web Audio API` and derivatives. This API is amazing. There are several ways of developing what I want with it however, the support is only for users with CHROME.

So the challenge is this. How do I develop a Multitrack Player as the sample page where audios touch without latency and the entire script development is compatible with all browsers?

Comment: There's always going to be latency, network lag etc, especially on a phone playing three tracks at once ?

Comment: Web Audio API certainly works on firefox as well as other modern browsers.  Perhaps the code you tried was using ancient obsolete calls.

Comment: @adeneo But in this case the sample page, there is no latency. Do you agree?

Comment: @ScottStensland I used the settings that the W3C has passed in the last update of the manual for Web Audio API ...

Comment: Do you mean to sync the tracks? Maybe you can check who it's implemented here: https://forestmist.org/blog/web-audio-api-loops (see the "findSync" function).